# IE Dev tools - outline margins and padding

Tags: internet-explorer

With IE Developer Tools is it possible to outline paddings and margins, like Firebug does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IE8, you can get the developer tools using F12, and then use the "Outline" menu to turn on table and cell outlines.

Along the top of the right-hand pane of the Developer Tools window, you'll see a "Layout" option.  If you select that, and then click on one of the DOM elements in the left-hand pane, the Layout" pane will display the padding, margin, etc. for the element you have selected.  That display supports in-place editing.

Comment: Too bad that doesn't work in IE 6 or 7 which are far worse than 8.